# How do I create a colormap in VTK?

Tags: python, c++, vtk

I created a simple unstructured square in VTK:

```
x = [0,10,0,10]
y = [0, 0, 10, 10]
z = [0,0,0,0]
data = np.asarray([x,y,z]).T
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    points.InsertPoint(i, data[i])
quad = [2,3,1,0]
ugrid.InsertNextCell(vtk.VTK_QUAD, 4, quad)
ugrid.SetPoints(points)
```

Say I wanted to create a colormap of the temperature across the square. I know the temperature at the corners:

```
 temp = [0,20,40,60]
```

How can I color the entire square knowing these values?

VTK provides one example to create a colormap in their tutorials (the ColoredElevationMap tutorial), however, I don't completely understand it and I believe there is another simpler way to create a colormap in VTK that I don't know of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add your data array and set it as the scalars (= default array to use in VTK, particularly for coloring)

```
temperature = vtk.vtkIntArray()
temperature.SetName("Temp")
temp = [00,20,40,60]
for t in temp:
    temperature.InsertNextValue(t)

ugrid.GetPointData().SetScalars(temperature)
```

Then in the rendering part, this array will be used by default for coloration. You still have to update the color range:

```
mapper.SetScalarRange(ugrid.GetScalarRange())
```

You can take a look to this [example](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/Rendering/Rainbow) (*edit*: update link thanks to @paulo-carvalho)

Comment: That link is no longer working.  Please, use this one: https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/Rendering/Rainbow/

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Nico Vuaille's answer. The color of the map can be changed using a lookup table such as:

```
lut = vtk.vtkLookupTable()
lut.SetHueRange(0, 0)
lut.SetSaturationRange(0, 0)
lut.SetValueRange(0.2, 1.0)
lut.Build()
```

and

```
Mapper.SetLookupTable(lut)
```

Comment: 1+ finest sample ever